# Puppet revokes OpenSSL certificates

Tags: ssl, puppet, openssl, certificate

I'm experiencing some certification revokations in the puppet master and this behavior seems to be random.

I just checked one of the CA certificates and I found this:

```
# openssl crl -text -in /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem 

Certificate Revocation List (CRL):
        Version 2 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: /CN=Puppet CA: puppet.master
        Last Update: Dec 16 11:55:15 2015 GMT
        Next Update: Dec 14 11:55:16 2020 GMT
        CRL extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:FF:9D:F6:0B:4A:17:27:A6:7D:DF:3A:8A:FC:D1:99:73:24:CA:87:08

            X509v3 CRL Number:
                83
Revoked Certificates:
    Serial Number: 02
        Revocation Date: Nov 18 10:55:38 2015 GMT
        CRL entry extensions:
            X509v3 CRL Reason Code:
                Key Compromise
```

...... (the output continues with several Revoked Certificates)

What does cause the OpenSSL "Key Compromise" error? No FQDN changes were made to the agent nor any system related file. Also I checked that the OpenSSL versions of the servers that has the certificates revoked are the same than other which certificate is valid: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-30

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Could you have run into this?

- Masterzen's Blog, 2010-11-14, [*Puppet SSL Explained*](http://www.masterzen.fr/2010/11/14/puppet-ssl-explained/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/PxoLu).)

> If for any reason you need to fully **re-install a given node without changing its fqdn**, either use the previous certificate or **clean this node certificate (which will automatically revoke the certificate for your own security**)

(Emphasis mine.)